# String value equals true

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a function that returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` or `"Test_operation"`, and I am looping it to do some things. As you can see the value of `$comment_reply` is `Test_operation`.

```
$comment_reply = $this->Profunction->insert_comments();
echo $comment_reply; // returns Test_operation
if ($comment_reply==TRUE)
{
    echo json_encode('Success');
}
elseif($comment_reply==FALSE)
{
    echo json_encode('Failed');
}
elseif($comment_reply =="test_operation")
{
    echo json_encode('This Action Cannot be done!');
}
```

But still

```
if ($comment_reply==TRUE)
{
    echo json_encode('Success');
}
```

This portion getting executed. Why does it happen?

In that function I am returning like this:

```
return TRUE;     // if all success
return FALSE;      // if there is some problems
return "Test_operation";     //No insertion need to be done,may be for preview purpose.
```

SOLVED : I changed `bool` values to string.
So it will be

```
return 'TRUE';     // if all success
    return 'FALSE';      // if there is some problems
    return "Test_operation";     //No insertion need to be done,may be for preview purpose.
```

Comment: You did not really "solve" the issue, you circumvented it by avoiding booleans.  Although in this case your solution works, string equality can be just as tricky with strings.  I really suggest when doing comparisons of the sort, use === to be totally sure type and value are compare.  Oh, and please don't forget to vote for the best answer, the acceptance rating for your posts is kind of low.  Thanks & good day to you.

Comment: @stefgosselin ohh sorry,i accepted your answer [The First Answer and Good explanation],its look like php is really bad when we compare to C#,but it is very easy to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure it's your issue, but if you want to enforce equality by type ***and*** value, use the `===` operator.

You can check this out in more detail on the [comparison operator page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Happy coding

Comment: Thank you ,But i think that i can avoid this if i avoid `boolean`.

Comment: As you wish, my friend. Boolean's are ok you just have to remember many things == true in php, whereas === will only return true for a bool like you expect.

Comment: I understand now , actually i am coming from c# and trying PHP now,thats the problem with me.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `===` instead of `==`