# How is it logical that a string equals TRUE in PHP

Tags: php

For the record, I know the solution is to use === instead of == . 
I'm just wondering what the logic behind it is. How is it logical that 'hello' can equal TRUE?

```
$var = TRUE;

if($var == 'hello'){  
    echo 'match';
}
else{
    echo 'no match';
}
```

The solution has been discussed, but I haven't seen any real explanation.
[String value equals true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253488/string-value-equals-true)

Comment: Consider `true` is a presence of something.

Comment: if you want an exact match I believe you are supposed to use "===" instead of "=="

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

== compares just the values of the variables whereas === compares variable values and type. so for an example:

```
1 == 1: true
1 === "1": false // "1" is a string and 1 is an integer
```

when asking if a string == true, you are essientially asking if it is set. Similar functionality is behind the isset() method.

If you were to compare "hello" === true. This would be false as they are of different type and "hello" would HAVE to equal "hello"

Comment: I understand why === works. But how does the value of 'hello' logically equal the value of true, i.e. 'hello' == true? There's nothing equivalent about it.

Comment: i added more to my answer which i think should clarify more

Comment: I also understand why  "hello" === true would be false, because it's comparing the type. But I still can't wrap my head around "string == true" being true because it's "essentially asking if it is set." I'm comparing the two. They aren't equal, therefore shouldn't be true. But it is true. I know you're probably explaining it the best it can be explained. I guess I just have to keep it in mind, and not try to be logical about it.

Comment: true/falso can be substituted as a 1 or a 0. Think of what a 1 and 0 zero means. In basic terms 1 == on and 0== off. Is string on? Is string off?

Answer (score 0):

When using == operator think in ***falsy*** and ***truthy*** terms.

So:

When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:

- the boolean FALSE itself
- the integers 0 and -0 (zero)
- the floats 0.0 and -0.0 (zero)
- the empty string, and the string "0"
- an array with zero elements
- the special type NULL (including unset variables)
- SimpleXML objects created from empty tags
- -1 is considered TRUE, like any other non-zero (whether negative or positive) number!

Every other value is considered TRUE (including any resource and NAN).

@see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php